# Removing six.b from multiple files

Tags: python, bash

I have dozens of files in the project and I want to change all occurences of `six.b("...")` to `b"..."`. Can I do that with some sort of regex bash script?

Comment: do you have occurrences of `six.b` that shouldn't change? e.g. `six.begin` or etc. You marked this as Python, are you open to a Python solution too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible entirely in Python, But I would first make a backup of my project tree, and then:

```
import re
import os

indir = 'files'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(indir):
    for f in files:
        fname = os.path.join(root, f)
        with open(fname) as f:
            txt = f.read()
        txt = re.sub(r'six\.(b\("[^"]*"\))', r'\1', txt)
        with open(fname, 'w') as f:
            f.write(txt)
        print(fname)
```

Comment: Isn't that going to keep the parentheses, turning `six.b("asdf")` into `b("asdf")`? I think it also gives wrong output for strings with escaped quotes, like `six.b("asdf\")")`. It doesn't handle `'` quotes or triple-quotes either, but at least it just doesn't touch those instead of producing mangled output.

Answer (score 1):

A relatively simple bash solution (change *.foo to *.py or whatever filename pattern suits your situation):

```
#!/bin/bash

export FILES=`find . -type f -name '*.foo' -exec egrep -l 'six\.b\("[^\"]*"\)' {} \; 2>/dev/null`
for file in $FILES
do
    cp $file $file.bak
    sed 's/six\.b(\(\"[^\"]*[^\\]\"\))/b\1/' $file.bak > $file
    echo $file
done
```

Notes:

1. It will only consider/modify files that match the pattern
2. It will make a '.bak' copy of each file it modifies
3. It won't handle embedded `\")`, e.g. `six.b("asdf\")")`, but I don't know that there is a trivial solution to that problem, without knowing more about the files you're manipulating. Is the end of `six.b("")` guaranteed to be the last `")` on the line? etc.