# Transforming declarative tests into pytest asserts

Tags: python, regex, pytest

I have a long script that is full of lines like this

```
[UBInt8.parse, b"\x01", 0x01, None],
[UBInt8.build, 0x01, b"\x01", None],
```

I need to turn them through regular expressions into

```
assert UBInt8.parse(b"\x01") == 0x01
assert UBInt8.build(0x01) == b"\x01"
```

Lists are always of length 4. 1st is method, 2nd is its argument, 3rd is return value, 4th is always None. I already used regex to solve a similar problem (someone produced the parser) but I need help writing the formatting string:

See [Removing six.b from multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39131755/removing-six-b-from-multiple-files) . This is the code I used before, the formatting expression needs to be rewritten and I dont speak regex. :(

```
import re
import os

indir = 'files'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(indir):
    for f in files:
        fname = os.path.join(root, f)
        with open(fname) as f:
            txt = f.read()
        txt = re.sub(r'six\.(b\("[^"]*"\))', r'\1', txt)
        with open(fname, 'w') as f:
            f.write(txt)
        print(fname)
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Edited. I attached the code here. The expression is what I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the manual parsing that I came up with. No regex.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import re, os, sys

def processfile(fname):
    print(fname+'... ')
    with open(fname, 'rt') as f:
        txt = f.readlines()
    with open(fname+"-trans", 'wt') as f:
        for line in txt:
            items = list(map(str.strip, line.strip().strip(",[]").split(",")))
            if len(items) == 4:
                if items[1] == "None":
                    items[1] = ""
                if items[3] == "None":
                    o = "assert {0}({1}) == {2}".format(*items)
                else:
                    if items[1] == "":
                        o = "assert raises({0}) == {3}".format(*items)
                    else:
                        o = "assert raises({0}, {1}) == {3}".format(*items)

                f.write("        "+o+"\n")
            else:
                f.write(line)

processfile(sys.argv[1])
```